# How could disabling sound increase framerate?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was reading about [frame rate on the Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Frame_rate) and saw this:

> ### Increasing FPS

> Disable sound effects. This is particularly effective when near a large amount of sound-producing blocks (lava, flowing water) or mobs.

I tested this myself near both lava and flowing water, and near a mob farm. I couldn't notice any difference in the framerate with sounds turned off compared to sounds turned on.

In theory, how could turning off sounds effect framerate?

Comment: it's not so much to do with the frame rate directly, but the cpu. If your using less on sound, you can spend more on other things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said in my comment above; your main CPU has to process sounds before they're sent to the sound card for output. This takes some CPU cycles away from the processing of everything else like graphics.

Just wanted to double check before I actually provided this as an answer.

Comment: Do you have any proof of this?

Comment: @Caleb You don't need proof, everything takes CPU cycles and sound too.

Comment: If you've ever noticed a lag spike while crossing a chunk boundary, it's often due to leaving/entering a chunk in which sounds are audible, especially if it's a lot of sounds. This doesn't prove directly that sound affects FPS but shows that they can definitely affect the performance of your game.

Answer (score 0):

Sound will affect fps because, the game still has to process the sounds, which take a bit of RAM.